# Asp.net file dialog set default folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filedialog

Is there any way to do this? I thought I'd find hundreds of results on google for this but not really finding anything. I want to set it to a location either on the web server or on a mapped networked drive somewhere.

I'm talking about with `<input type="file" ... />` to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. This runs on the client, and for security reasons you can't interfere with the client's filesystem through Javascript.

It is however possible using a flash or Silverlight plugin, as the user can allow access from within these applications to the local filesystem. It would cause alot more code though.